# priority queue function compare

Tags: c++, boolean, compare, priority-queue

In the code below, when used in a priority queue, is the compare item the item that is being pushed?
Thus, in the `Mycomp` function, is `pair &a` the object being added, and `pair &b`, already in the queue and being compared against?

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    struct Mycomp {
        bool operator()(const pair<int, string> &a, const pair<int, string> &b){
            
            if(a.first != b.first) { // comparing the frequency if it is not same then return the one with smallest frequency
                return a.first > b.first;
            }else{
                // if frequency are same then compare the alphabetical order - should return the largest one as the idead is to pop smallest frequency with 
                // largest alphabetical order
                return a.second < b. second;
            }
        }
    };

    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
        
        //defining a map to keep track of the frequency of the words
        std::unordered_map<string, int> hashMap;

        for( auto word : words) {
            hashMap[word]++;
        }
        
        // Now we use the concept of priority queue 
        std::priority_queue<pair<int, string>,std::vector<pair<int,string>>, Mycomp> pq ;
        
        for(auto ele : hashMap) {
            pq.push({ele.second, ele.first});
            
            if(pq.size() > k) {
                pq.pop(); // pop the elements with least frequency
            }
        }
        
        vector<string> result;
        while(k--){
            result.insert(result.begin(),pq.top().second); // if you use push back, then you need to reverse the vector as pq returns the highest alpabetical order when popping.
            pq.pop();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: This question is not related to bool operator overloading

Comment: ah, is int operator overloading? what is this considered?

Comment: If you're interested in how does `Compare` work, you may use debugger and check `&a` and `&b`.

Comment: @leon It's [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Answer (score 0):

No. The first parameter is not the object being added.

The second parameter of your `operator()`, usually the object just added.

Usually the first parameter is mid element of your queue.

But again, in some cases, there is a chance of these behaviors unexpected and depends on compilers or algorithms used.